# Want to buy a car but have not enough money

Tags: savings, budget, financial-advisor, sri-lanka

I'm still at a very early stage of my professional career and my salary is still very low. I work in the IT field. I have a dream of buying my own car. The current price of my desired car is 200 times my current monthly salary. I try my best to save some money, but after six months, I'm not happy with what I've got. Is there any way for me to either try to save more or something else I can do to achieve what I need to do? Any idea is welcome.

I've cut off all my expenses except the things I need to live (food, residency fees etc..). I'm not trying to buy a car right away but I'd like to get it within next 10-12 months. I'm not getting salary increment soon, since in IT field, to get bigger salary, I should have work experience, which I don't have at this time.

**Update**

I'm currently living in Sri Lanka.

Comment: Welcome to money site. The question as you have asked is not the right fit for this site. There are only 2 options for you, either increase your salary or reduce your dream.

Comment: 200 times your annual salary is a lot, what kind of car are you after??!! Joking aside please clarify which period's salary you mean, 200 times my daily salary is quite a lot less than 200 times my annual salary and I guess that's true for you too. Id does look like you are being a bit ambitious with what car you can afford.

Comment: @MD-Tech car prices are being double because of tax policy in my country. price become double after the tax. I live in asian country. I meant 200 times my monthly salary. and vehicle I wanted to buy is a Honda vezel. In original manufacturer price, its lot less than final retail price. my mind is set to that vehicle. I dont need to buy it right away, but I'd love to have it within next 10-12 months

Comment: @Dheer Im trying to increase my salary, but my mind is set to that car. thanks for the answer..

Comment: Well you're obviously not going to be able to afford a car that is 200 times your monthly salary in a timeframe of 10-12 months without something drastic changing, such as a huge increase in salary or a sizable inheritance. Just saving up is not likely, since even at a fairly optimistic rate of saving 50% of your salary you're still looking at a timeframe of more than 30 years. If the numbers you provided are even close to accurate, no lender in their right mind would consider loaning you the money, either.

Comment: Have you considered buying a used version of the model you are interested in? You would be able to afford it much sooner.

Comment: @Joey please add a country tag.

Comment: what car could you want that costs 200x your monthly salary!? Unless you're talking something like a Bugatti Veyron ... or you're only making $200/mo ...

Comment: @Nosrac above mentioned price is for used version. (roughly less than 2 years used)

Comment: @RonJohn updated my question

Comment: @warren its Honda vezel. due to tax policy in my country, final retail price is somewhat doubled or more on usual price. also yeah, my current salary is roughly 200$/mo

Comment: Can you work an additional part-time job? You can focus on learning something more lucrative so that you can get a better paying job. Also, I don't love the approach, but I see many people who over-state their experience in order to get a job that's maybe a little beyond what they are qualified for.

Comment: If you buy a car 200x your monthly salary, you are giving up on all future financial security for a luxury item. If you can continue to bike / walk / take public transit to work, you should do that.  Don't count on getting promotions in the future when you make your budget - the future isn't here yet, and counting on things that haven't happened can lead to disaster if things take longer than you expected.

Comment: @Joey - when I lived in Singapore, cars had a ~190% tax (a Mazda3 was $63000 - the "base price" was only about $25-27k).

But that was a plausible price for the inclined to save for and buy. If you're only making ~$200/mo, you need to either: move to somewhere that pays better, find a better-paying job where you are, or pick a different vehicle to buy. You will ***never*** be able to afford a $40,000 car making $200/month

Comment: @HartCO I tried that. but considering my current job, most of the time I end up with no time for do other things. jobs are hard here..more work, lesser payments. When applying for a new job, what they look almost each time is job experience.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon its not very much a luxury item, Im more than willing to use public transportation as long as I'm able to save enough money. I hear you, your advise is golden-> " on't count on getting promotions in the future when you make your budget - the future isn't here yet "...  But main thing is I want to do it soon. cant wait for few years, my target is in less than 1 or 1.5 years. could I do that? what should I do?

Comment: @warren I am trying to save, but had no luck yet. what should I do to achieve this target sooner? I mean I can wait for a year or little more, but thats it. About your suggestions, my field is IT. do you know where I can move to which has higher payment options? Im trying to get better pay, but my lack of job experience makes it even harder. I know I'll **never** get my car if Im in this salary. just looking for other options, if there's any that I can do

Comment: @Joey You are ignoring the most common advice people are providing - that the car you want is too expensive for your salary. And yes, the car truly is a 'luxury' to you, as it costs 200x your salary and you don't need it to get to work.

Comment: @Joey - many folks here have told you what you need to do: find a better paying job or pick a cheaper car. Those are your options.

Comment: Thanks for advice and all the helpful words Grade'Eh'Bacon, warren . I will follow that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When your dream car is not just 200 times your disposable income but in fact 200 times your whole monthly salary, then there is no way for you to afford it right now. Any attempt to finance through a loan would put you into a debt trap you won't ever dig yourself out.

And if there are any car dealerships in your country which claim otherwise, run away fast. Jon Oliver from Last Week tonight made [a video about business practices of car dealerships in the United States which sell cars on loans to people who can't afford them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U2eDJnwz_s) a while ago. As usual: When a deal seems too good to be true, it generally isn't true at all. After a few months, the <s>victims</s> customers usually end up with no car but lots of outstanding debt they pay off for years.

So how do you tell if you can afford a car or not?

A new car usually lives for about 10-20 years. So when you want to calculate the monthly cost of owning a new car, divide the price by 120. But that's just the price for *buying* the vehicle, not for actually *driving* it. Cars cost additional money each month for gas, repairs, insurance, taxes etc. (these costs depend a lot on your usage pattern and location, so I can not provide you with any numbers for that). If you have less disposable income per month (as in "money you currently have left at the end of each month") than monthly cost of purchase plus expected monthly running costs, you can not afford the car.

Possible alternatives:

- Look for a cheaper car which is more in your price range. Used cars are far cheaper than new ones (but do of course have less lifetime left). But keep in mind that *very* old cars are usually more expensive in maintenance cost, because they will require more repairs. So a old clunker from the junk yard might in the end be more expensive than a used car in good condition.
- Subscribe to a car sharing service where you can rent a car for an affordable fee when you need one.
- See if you can find a job which either pays better or provides you with a company car

Comment: Yes, used car.  I make plenty of money and haven't bought a new car in over 10 years.  Normally at least 2 years old but 4 is better as you get rid of much of the depreciation.

Comment: Can you update your question based on the new information that OP has included in their comments? The parts which reference US practices are not very relevant to someone living in Sri Lanka. Also, OP is also already considering a used car. +1 for the rest of your answer

Comment: @AbraCadaver the price I mentioned above is for a used car. used for roughly 1-2 years. sorry i dont understand by what you meant on older than 4 year is better because of detting rid on deprication

Comment: @Nosrac I updated the question. is there something more that I need to say in my question?

Comment: @Philipp price of the car I want to buy is - if brand new,~11million LKR , if used, 6.5 - 7 million LKR. And I did the calculation and got the answer as **NO** not even for the buying. my current income is ~30000 LKR. So I understand its merely impossible to me to get it right now. About your solutions, My mind is set to this vehicle, most of the cheaper cars are expensive in parts and maintenance. so it could be very same after all. There're no car sharing services in my country.only rentals.
Seems like last option is all I have right now.my field is IT.any advice in that area?

Comment: @Joey Sorry, but I am not familiar with the job market situation in Sri Lanka.

Comment: @Philipp no no i meant internationally, im willing to move if i get better opportunity

Comment: @Joey - there are loads of places that hire IT personnel all over the world. You might be able to stay as close as India or Singapore, or move to Korea, Austrailia, Canda, or any of scores of other countries. The ball is in your court on this.

Comment: @Joey: At least in the US, as soon as you buy a new car it is worth less than what you paid and it decreases in value pretty rapidly for the first 4 years.  So when you buy new or less than 4 years old or so, it is rapidly losing value. At 4 years it does not decrease as much so if you wanted to sell it for whatever reason it might be worth closer to the price you paid.

Comment: @warren how can I find such a job in other country, lets say canada or australia. is there any procedure?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think its also similar here regarding decreasing value.but I didn't get what happens after the 4th year. you saying if I need to buy a used car, then I should consider buy a car less than 4 years? after 4 years its value increase? is that right?

Comment: @Joey You will likely require a visa to work in most other countries. But this topic is not on-topic for this answer or actually this whole site in general. Check https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ if you have questions about migrating to another country.

Comment: @Philipp thanks, I'll give it a try. appreciate your help.